# Uncaught TypeError: action.serialize is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

This is my code looks like:

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
    <div class="row top-buffer">
        <div class="col-cs-6 col-md-8">
            <input type="param" id="name2" name="value" class="form-control" value="test2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-cxs-6 col-md-4">
            <button type='submit' value='test' class='send button btn btn-danger'>Lägg till</button> <!-- changed -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<form id="form2" method="post">
    <div class="row top-buffer">
        <div class="col-cs-6 col-md-8">
            <input type="param" id="name2" name="value" class="form-control" value="test">
        </div>
        <div class="col-cxs-6 col-md-4">
            <button type='submit' value='delist' class='send button btn btn-danger'>Ta bort</button> <!-- changed -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
$(".send").click(function() {
    var myform = $(this).closest("form");
    var sForm = myform.serialize();
    var action = $(this).val();
    var sAction = $(this).val().serialize();;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: sForm, sAction,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#response').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Currently I receive the following error:

> whitelist.php:67 Uncaught TypeError: action.serialize is not a function(…)

If I change the `data` to the following, I don't get any errors but, the array is broken.

```
data: { mySform, 'Param': action },
```

The array ends up looking like this:

```
Array
(
    [mySform] => value=test2
    [Param] => test
)
```

To clarify a few things, what I want is the array to look like this:

```
Array ( [Param] => value [Action] => value )
```

and I need my jQuery to be able to work with more than 3 forms. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm very new to jQuery and AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you're getting the `serialize is not a function` error because you're calling it on a string. It's intended to be called on a `form` element contained within a jQuery object.

Secondly, you need to append the value of the clicked button to the querystring which is generated from the `serialize()` method.

Lastly, to stop the form submission in the correct manner you should hook the event to the `form` element itself. Try this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    var action = $form.find('.send').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: $form.serialize() + '&action=' + action,
        // data: $form.serialize() + '&' + $.param({ action: action }) // alternative
        success: function(data) {
            $('#response').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```